# Is it a good practice to use nested switches in C++? Is there any alternative method to avoid this?

Tags: c++, methods

Currently I am having a function which has two arguments of type enums, the function requires to compare both and do particular task
example:

```
 void set_Test_Status(Tests TestName, Status TestStatus)
 {
    switch(TestName)
    {
         case Tests::Test1:
              {
                 switch(TestStatus)
                 {
                     case TestStatus::St1:
                     //Rest of Code
                 }
              }
           //Rest of Code
    }
 }
```

is it a good programming practice? or is there any alternative method or style of coding that i should be aware of? Thank you!

Edit:
Finally after trial and error, I did this. First i saw the maximum and minimum items in each enums, In my case TestName were 6 and TestStatus had 3. I created 3 functions setStatusRunning(Tests TestName), setStatusSelected(Tests TestName) and setStatusFinished(Tests TestName) and in set_Test_status, using switch(TestName) i check which function should be called and then called the appropriate functions. The reason i had to make set_Test_Status in the first place was to make easy for other classes, since i made set_Test_Status public and the other 3 as private.

Comment: As long as the code is concise in what it's meant to do, well organized and formed; it is legal valid C++ code. I've seen this kind of structure in menu selections, keyboard - mouse input for window message handlers etc. Just make sure that you have the appropriate breaks, continues and returns.

Comment: if ( TestName==Tests::Test1 && TestStatus==TestStatus::St1 ) {.. } else if ...

Comment: Nested ifs are usually bad. Nested switches are worse.

Comment: Try making another function.

Comment: @FrancisCugler And what if the code in the inner switch is fairly large? Should i create another function that takes second enum as argument?

Comment: Whether something is a good practice is usually opinion based.

Comment: As Linus Torvalds claims, "if you need more than 3 indentation levels, you're screwed".

Comment: Avoid nesting, try to keep it modular using functions .

Comment: If they are 1 - 2 statements each then a nested switch isn't bad, but if there is lots of code within a single case statement then yes, refine the code and put those code blocks into functions.

Comment: Looks good to me. Isn't up to 7 levels of indentation considered acceptable? Or a table of `std::function` might be better, particularly if all the functions have the same parameters or even arity.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions, I'll keep the nested switches and try to keep the code in the inner switch as small as possible

Comment: @Bathsheba - 7??

Comment: Maybe, you should refactor one of the switches into a virtual method call. Btw., your cases are missing `break` statements, braces `{}` are not enough to stop fall-through execution. I hope the `break`s are present in the original code.

Comment: This is essentially asking for opinion. You haven't even told us, which aspect of the code you want changed, or why. Not a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I have that down as one of the universal constants.

Comment: @Bathsheba - When you say 7, do you mean from the beginning of the line, or the current function scope? I just realized we may not be measuring from the same reference point.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Up to 7 levels from the global namespace.

Comment: If it compiles builds and runs; I don't care. If they can not read my 1024 indentations I can consider it obfuscation! LOL; JK!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is truly a matter of opinion as having nested switch statements is valid c++ code. Some may not have problems with it while others may argue that it can be confusing.

My advice would be on the lines of this; if the code blocks within the case statements are short such as 1-2 lines and they are fairly easy to read and follow, then there should be nothing wrong with it. However, if the code is quite cumbersome and the nested switch statements spans well over 50 to 100+ lines then I would suggest refining your code and make functions out of them.

Examples:

```
// should be okay

unsigned int outerSwitch = someValue(); 
unsigned int innerSwitch = someOtherValue();
switch ( outerSwitch ) {
    case 1: {
        switch ( innerSwitch ) {
            case 1 : {
                // 1 or 2 lines okay;  
            } 
            case 2 : {
                // 1 or 2 lines okay;
            }
            case 3 : {
                // 1 or 2 lines okay;
            }
            default : {

            }
        } // inner switch when outer switch case = 1
    }
    case 2: {
          // Same as case 1
    }
    case 3: {
          // Same as case 1
    }
    default: {

    }
} // outer switch
```

But as you have seen above with just 3 cases to the outer and inner; it gets very long very quickly and I haven't even expanded them all. So this can be frowned upon.

You can have a single switch as others have suggested that calls a specific function to that switch then within that function it has its own switch statement like this:

```
unsigned int someFuncA( unsigned int someVal ) {
    switch ( someVal ) {
        case 1 : {
            // do this
            // return that;   
        }
        case 2: {
            // ... etc.
        }
    } // switch
} 

unsigned int someFuncB( int someVal ) {
    // similar to someFuncA();
}

unsigned int someFuncC( int someVal ) {
    // similar to someFuncA();
}

unsigned int switchValue = someValue();
unsigned int innerValue = someOtherFunction();
unsigned int temp = 0;
switch( switchValue ) {
    case 1 : {
        temp = someFuncA( innerValue );
        // either return temp, break, continue, or fall through
    }
    case 2 : {
        temp = someFuncB( innerValue );
        // same as above
    case 3 : {
        temp = someFuncC( innerValue );
        // same as above
    }
    default : {
        // default stuff here
    }   
} // switch
```

Comparing the two you will see that the 2nd version is easier to read and less cumbersome than the 1st. Yes the first version is valid legal C++ code, but is frowned upon because of how messy it can easily and quickly get. So where ever you can; turn that code into a function that is designed to do just that one thing.

**EDIT**

Another possibility is to design specific functions to do a task and as you said that your function takes 2 different enumeration values, you can look up the concept of functions that are designed to take bit flags. You will see this kind of code quite a bit in windows programming as well as OpenGL.

Another option is this: consider that fact you have an outer control switch, and inner control switch. Even if you have multiple cases, each case is independent with a specific unique ID. The same can be said for the inner switch cases. Knowing this you can create an associative mapping of all the statements in a combined matter using `std::multimap<unsigned, unsigned> testCases` and with this lookup table you can have it in a single statement with independent function calls to each map entry. [cppreference : std::multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Your map might look like this:

```
testCases[1][1];
testCases[1][2];
testCases[1][3];
testCases[2][1];
testCases[2][2];
testCases[2][3];
testCases[3][1];
testCases[3][2];
testCases[3][3];
```

Where each index of the map is the logic or calculation you want to perform.

Answer (score 2):

It can be quite confusing for someone reading the code-- indentation helps, but it can still be difficult to follow where the case and switch statements start and end. Most IDEs have support for finding a matching brace, but finding a matching break isn't generally a thing, so it can be difficult to even see where a case statement ends. (And technically case doesn't define scope whereas braces do, so it doesn't even have an end.)

If you get misaligned braces or accidentally mismatch where they should be, you can have odd things happen. Languages like Ada try to prevent that with strongly typed English-language specifiers.

If you are doing a lot of sub-switches, I would put them into another function and call it with the information it needs, then you could do a switch statement inside the method which is more modular, separate scope and clear what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice to keep code concise is to do only one thing in a function. Using a switch already is a smell that your function is going to do different things. It all depend of your specific case.

One thing to look at is: is it coherent to manage all these cases in one class. Should you have one class per possibility, with an interface forcing to implement a function, instead of doing all the possibilities in a switch case.

In case you want to keep the switch, a good practice would be to not put code in it other than the switch. Each case just calls a function. This will already make stuff more readable.

Finally, are you using all the cases? If no, you code could be more clear by just implementing the pairs of values that you need:

```
if(TestName == Tests::Test1 && TestStatus == TestStatus::St1)
{
    doThing();
}
```

**To summarize:**

This might be a smell that your code needs to be split in more classes to have only one responsibility per class (too many if and/or too many switches ar a sign of that). If you are sure that you need a switch, keep it as simple and clear as possible

Comment: Yes I am using all the cases, so i can not use if else ladder, but i think the code in inner switch is fairly small so ill try implementing nested switches. Thanks!

Comment: @guru • as an exercise, for your top level switch's case statements, take the entire body of each of those case statements and put each one in a separate function.  That way `set_Test_Status` is doing one thing:  delegating by case.

Comment: @Eljay Yes i have done, I created 3 functions setStatusRunning(Tests TestName), setStatusSelected(Tests TestName) and setStatusFinished(Tests TestName) and in set_Test_status, using switch(TestName) i check which function should be called and then called the appropriate functions.Thank you for help!